# Cómo aislar el link directo de una imagen cuando scrapeo un sitio?

Tags: python

soy nuevo en esto del scrape, estoy extrayendo informacion de un ranking de video juegos, específicamente estoy usando esta página: *http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=Elfwinny* y quiero extraer el enlace directo del "avatar" que se muestra en el ranking, el codigo que he desarrollado hasta hoy (usando BeautifulSoup) esta basado en una lista donde solo me muestra el tercer resultado(indexado como 2) y me ha llevado a tener este output:

```
<img class="avatar" src="http://msavatar1.nexon.net/Character/DMKBFLAHBBIEOHBLDKKPOILGFNLMMDFHJAHADFBLBAHEBLDNBPEDJGENLEDDIBCMADPJJDONBCLOGIPMADOOGCOJEFCKJPLEEHDMLDHAPFGLLIIMAJGIOAJFFNGPNLMJDNFANAFODFAPMOJFCMPMOJKIEOAKCHEILFEKCMMPKBNGKDKHLMMNMKFOBNBGOMPPJBBPFAFICNNBKAAEBGGDACNDIFPOLPIHFHOIMPONIEJMJNDAJFINCLBGMKHOKGAB.png"/>
```

Sin embargo, quisiera saber cómo obtener unicamente lo que esta dentro del SRC, o sea, el enlace directo de la imagen unicamente. No necesito descargarlo, unicamente que imprima el enlace directo:

```
http://msavatar1.nexon.net/Character/DMKBFLAHBBIEOHBLDKKPOILGFNLMMDFHJAHADFBLBAHEBLDNBPEDJGENLEDDIBCMADPJJDONBCLOGIPMADOOGCOJEFCKJPLEEHDMLDHAPFGLLIIMAJGIOAJFFNGPNLMJDNFANAFODFAPMOJFCMPMOJKIEOAKCHEILFEKCMMPKBNGKDKHLMMNMKFOBNBGOMPPJBBPFAFICNNBKAAEBGGDACNDIFPOLPIHFHOIMPONIEJMJNDAJFINCLBGMKHOKGAB.png
```

Mi código actual esta asi:

```
# Importamos las librerias
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import os
import re

 # Capturamos la url 
html = urlopen('http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=Elfwinny')

# Creamos el objeto soup y le pasamos lo capturado con request
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
avatar = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.png')})
print(avatar[2])
```

Gracias por leer de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peudes usar el metodo `get` para el elemento

```
avatar = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.png')})
print(avatar[2]["src"])    
print(avatar[2].get("src")) //equivalente
```

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias!